# ansible: reference to a variable from the same list

Tags: list, variables, ansible

i have a list like this (shortend for the example)

```
vars:  
 cli:  
   terraform:  
     bin_name: "terraform"
     source_url: "https://releases.hashicorp.com.."  
     bin_to_copy: "/tmp/{{ bin_name }}"
```

why is it not possible to access {{ bin_name }} name later? I tried w/ cli.bin_name; item.bin_name; item.key.b....
error is always: FAILED! => {"msg": "'bin_name' is undefined"}

Comment: Did you try `{{ cli.terraform.bin_name }}`?

Comment: yes but... :-/

Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: recursive loop detected in template string: {{ download_dir }}/{{ cli.terraform.bin_name }}"}

Comment: Well, there's your answer.  Can't do recursive.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. See [Can't reference a dict key inside the same dict #50280](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280).

FWIW. Take the common values out of the dictionary. For example

```yaml
vars:  
  my_bin_name: "terraform"
  cli:  
    terraform:  
      bin_name: "{{ my_bin_name }}"
      source_url: "https://releases.hashicorp.com.."  
      bin_to_copy: "/tmp/{{ my_bin_name }}"
```